# How to minify and combine Javascript and CSS

Tags: c#, javascript, minify

Can someone give me pointers on how I can minify and combine my CSS as the site I'm working on has performance issues.  Also, are external JS and CSS libraries also minified and combined or left as is?

Comment: Also, do I need separate tools to perform the minification and combination or would one tool do?

Comment: Does anyone know if external libraries are usually minified?

Comment: You can normally tell if external libs are minified by their name, as they have "min" in it, e.g. with jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several convenient options for .NET, for example:

[Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)

[SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt)

[Cassette](http://getcassette.net/)

And new in ASP.NET 4.5:
[Bundling in ASP.NET 4.5](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx)

Comment: Isn't Minify a php app? Anyway, if it does what you need - why not?

Comment: I don't know how Minify works - but with all the available .NET options available there isn't much reason to find out IMO. Just try one of the tools I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend reading Google's [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) and their [Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

Answer (score 2):

I would also add [RequestReduce](http://requestreduce.com) for .net options. It may be the only runtime bundling option for minifying external resources. Its unique from the other .net options in that it grabs the unminified content via http instead of via the file system. It can also sprite your background images.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I thought I will give a better answer (trick).

In visual studio if you do format code (Ctrl + K + D) then css will be formatted nicely for you.

Comment: No offense but It has nothing to do with the question, he's asking about a popular subject named code minification and you are telling him about the visual studio auto format feature to make the code nice and tidy.